# who uses a TCP port?

Tags: tcp, erlang

One of gen_servers in my app call [gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, true}])](https://github.com/egon-sim/egon_server/blob/b3a1cddaa46fe1c399ec93b2348b7bb16220adbb/src/es_connection_server.erl#L9). First time I run unit test, it returns {ok, Socket}, but second time I run the same unit test, it returns an {error, eaddrinuse}, but

```
lsof -i TCP
```

returns nothing. Also, when the same unit_test is run twice on another machine (WinXP), it works as expected (that is, returns {ok, Socket} both times). Therefore, my gen_server obviously releases the port, but Erlang somehow doesn't know that.

So, how can I figure out who does Erlang think uses this address?

Comment: You can use the reuseaddr flag to gen_tcp:listen to make this behaviour on Linux go away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of details of the implementation of TCP on Unix systems-- when a socket is opened for listening, it will stay unavailable for a few minutes in the CLOSE_WAIT state after the listening process shuts down.

From Lukas' comment above: you can use reuseaddr flag to gen_tcp:listen to avoid this

Comment: Oh how I love stack overflow :-D

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows you can use the netstat utility to find out which process has which port opened:

http://commandwindows.com/netstat.htm

`netstat -a -b -v` should do the trick

Linux netstat also supports showing the user, but you need root right for that.